# Can four probe method be used to find resistivity of metals?

Tags: electrical-resistance, conductors, electronics

Can we use four probe method to find resistivity of metal/conductor. I searched the question on google, but could not find the answer. My guess is that we can use. Why not?

Comment: Just do the experiment!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why the four point method shouldn't work on a metal surface just like on a semiconductor.

Comment: Having used a four point probe many times back in my metal film CVD days I have to agree. One would choose a different head so the spacing was appropriate to the resistivity, but it all worked just fine.